# How to inject context to Model class in MVP Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I am learning how to use MVP pattern and Dagger 2. I have injected presenters to views, and models to presenters based on tutorials but I cannot figure out how to inject "external" things like application/context to one of my model classes.I have read something about creating ContextModule but I still don't know how to make it work with my classes.
So i have:

**SettingsActivity** - view class

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

@Inject
lateinit var settingsPresenter: SettingsPresenter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)

    var component: SettingsComponent = DaggerSettingsComponent.create()
    component.inject(this)
}

}
```

**SettingsPresenter** - presenter class with mvp interfaces

```
class SettingsPresenter : BasePresenter<SettingsContract.View>, SettingsContract.Presenter{

     var settings: SettingsModel

    @Inject
    constructor(settings: SettingsModel) : super() {
        this.settings = settings
    }
}

interface SettingsContract {
    interface View
    interface Presenter
}

@Component
interface SettingsComponent {
    fun inject(settingsActivity: SettingsActivity)
}
```

**SettingsModel** - model class

```
class SettingsModel {

    @Inject
    constructor() {
    }
//I'd like to have my context field here
    @Inject
    lateinit var context: Context
}
```

**AppModule** - class I wanted to use to provide context

```
@Module
class AppModule {
    var context: Context

    constructor(context: Context) {
        this.context = context
    }

    @Provides
    fun getAppContext() : Context {
        return context.applicationContext
    }
}
```

How am I suppose to inject context to SettingsModel and where to start it?

Comment: What's the point of MVP pattern if the model or presenter directly communicates to `Context`? What exactly are you trying to solve with the pattern?

Comment: I need an access to read/save data using shared preferences. Is it better to inject shared preferences to SettingsModel?

Comment: If you want to talk to SharedPreferences, then why are you providing Context instead of SharedPreferences? :p

Comment: I am going to need context for using database, shared preferences and probably something more. Yesterday I tried to inject SharedPreferences but I still don't know how to do it directly in Model not in View(Activity) :/

Comment: Then why not provide the Database, and the SharedPreferences? Or something that wraps the SharedPreferences so that you don't see it, technically. Also, you can use ApplicationContext for these

Comment: But all of these things are context dependent so how can I inject them inside Model? According to this example https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Dependency-Injection-with-Dagger-2 in the end there is an injection in activity. Am I wrong thinking that I cannot inject these fields inside Model because ComponentBuilder has its place inside Activity?

Comment: Pass the `Context` (`MyApplication as Context`) into the singleton component via `@BindsInstance`. Then you can use it in modules like `@Provides fun sharedPref(context: Context): SharedPreferences = context.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`. Now you can use shared pref as `class MyManagerImpl @Inject constructor(private val sharedPref: SharedPreferences): MyManager`, for which you can create a `@Binds abstract fun myManager(impl: MyManagerImpl)`. Voila, you talk to `MyManager`, but internally it uses `SharedPreferences` as part of its implementation details, resolved auto by Dagger. Good job!

Comment: Thank you Master for a piece of good advice!